# Get string value and add to specific variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I want to get the value in an array and i want to put it in a variable

This is the array `{1,eli}`

```
CsvValues = RowData.Split(new string[] {","},
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);  // RowData is {1,eli}

List<string> elements = new List<string>();

foreach (string data in CsvValues)
{
    elements.Add(data);
}
```

and then I want to put it here:

```
 result.Add(new wsSample()
            {
                id = elements[0],
                name = elements[1]
            });
```

How will i add the elements value to id and name?

```
public class wsSample
{
    [DataMember]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is your solution not working? Is there an error?

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: That just means that your elements list is empty. Check that it has values before trying to access it.

Comment: Are you sure `elements` contains two strings? If it contains less than two strings then `elements[0]` and/or `elements[1]` will throw an error.

Comment: is there any way how will i put the value to id and name?

Comment: how will i add two string in my list elements

Comment: public class wsSample
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

Comment: CsvValues = RowData.Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: RowData is the {1,eli}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the rest of the input array structured?

If it is `elements = {"1","eli", "2","manning"}`
then you might be better off using a for loop.

I think this is what you are looking for

```
  List<wsSample> samples = new List<wsSample>();
    for(int i=0; i< elements.length-1; ++i) 
    {
        samples.Add(new wsSample()
        {
            id = elements[i]
            name = elements[i+1]
        });
        i= i+2;
    }
```